# Using pymysql - unicode

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pymysql

I'm trying to using pymysql for database connection.
But when I call procedure and get unicode value result, it breaks.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=pw, db=db, charset='utf8mb4', use_unicode=True)
cs = conn.cursor()
cs.callproc('procedure_name', (arg, ))
for row in cs:
    str=row[0]
```

The unicode data in str, it views "\ub2e4\uc0b0\uc9c0\uc564\uc9c0-\uc5f0\uad6c"
It means "다산지앤지-연구소".
I'm trying encode and decode, it just be more like byte-style.
How can I solve this problem?